# SQL Server Management Studio 2014 IS ALREADY INSTALLED HOW CAN I RESOLVE THIS ISSUE?

Tags: database, model-view-controller, c#-4.0, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-migrations

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)

Comment: You will get more help if you don’t SHOUT AT US but do format your question properly and explain what you’ve tried. Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you verified that SQL Server (not Management Studio) is installed and running, like the error message says?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Management studio is a client to connect to the SQL Server.

Please tell us which instance you decided to connect, it is in the local machine or remote machine.

Besides please check the server name you input in the box is correct and the SQL Server service is running.

You can check the SQL Server service via the Sql Server Configuration Manager.